# Text rotate within Uncode theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to attempt this pen that I found on code pen. It allows text to look like it is being typed and deleted.

I have attempted to put this is in the site, the html and java is in and I put the css in as well, but it doesn't seem to work any ideas?

I am using a theme within Wordpress called Uncode. I am able to put in raw Java and html blocks, but not css, I can put the css into the theme options or the page.

This page is a work in progress but here is the link to what is on the page: http://preview.geomedia.co.uk/whitelight-venues/about-us/

Comment: "this pen" where is the link or any code which one you tried to use?

Comment: [link] (https://codepen.io/CheeseTurtle/pen/jzdgI)

Answer (score -1):

Add css and javascript into footer.php at the end of file 
also, you need to call jquery-mini.js

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

  var that = this;
  var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #666 }";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
};
</script>
<style>

h1,h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0.4em 0;
}
h1 { font-size: 3.5em; }
h2 {
  color: #888;
  font-size: 2em;
}

</style>
```

After that create a template for your about us page it should be different from other pages and will going to use only this page.

Now into this template code, you can paste the HTML where you would like to show the text.

At the end, the result will look like this screenshot:  https://prnt.sc/hb69cf

It is working for me on my localshot website.

Thanks

Comment: Ok soI have gone too: appearance > editor > Uncode: Theme Footer (footer.php) > then I have scrolled down and put the code line which is above > then the Java code > under this then the Css > now I template the about page.

Comment: Where to I go to add the HTML section to this page, do I use a raw HTML block?

Comment: maybe work with raw sections note sure but try to add into template

Comment: so is the first step I mentioned correct with the placement of the code?

Comment: Have you managed to look at this, I have attempted this, however I can't seem to get this working. Could you please answer this in a step by step process?

Comment: ok did you check your console any error regarding the script?

Comment: Yeah no errors it seems to go through: http://preview.geomedia.co.uk/whitelight-venues/about-us/
This is the page now with all the code added? Obviously not working.

Comment: Dear you added all css and js completely wrong    https://prnt.sc/hbmhn3

Comment: I have now removed all of my errors, but I am left with where I got to with your answer yesterday

Comment: OK first open footer.php  and paste the code of css into <style></style> and javascript code into <script></script>

Comment: also call there  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   this script

Comment: Do I put that link in the top of the script tag?

Comment: now send me screenshot where you would like to appear the html code into about us page

Comment: This is where I would like this to go, http://prntscr.com/hbmoox

it seems the code has actually gone into the footer?

Comment: please you again put wrong code without any script start or end  https://prnt.sc/hbmqha   if you not understand please check my profile and contact me

Comment: I actually put in 2 script tag I removed one now it works

Comment: OK nice find this class into your about us template post-content and add below the html code

Comment: Would you mind just expanding on this, I don't really understand that, currently I now have a massive black border around all of my pages?

Comment: OK the css which one you put into footer replace all with this   
h1,h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0.4em 0;
}
h1 { font-size: 3.5em; }
h2 {
  color: #888;
  font-size: 2em;
}